# Deployed app on meteor but error from console

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I got a project that i have deployed on meteor

However, i get this error when looking in console:

Uncaught Error: Oh no! No route found for path: "/"

I have tried debug mode and --production server on localhost and it is working correctly,

but not on meteor after deployment.

I Really dont know where to look further.

Comment: Can you show your code for your `"/"` route?

Comment: `Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function () {

  this.route('indexify', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'indexify'
  });

  this.route('elements', {
    path: '/elements'
  });

});`

Comment: @user3202532 Is this problem still occurring?